# How to build and run a c++ application as release in Visual Studio Code

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, release, launch

It seems that launch configurations have to be run using the debugger. I can not find a launch type that does not use a debugger, and I can not find a vscode plug-in that allows for multiple run configurations.

My launch.json looks like this:

```
{
"name": "C++ Launch",
"type": "cppdbg",
"request": "launch",
"program": "${workspaceRoot}/a.out",
"args": ["arg1", "arg2"],
"environment": [{"name": "squid", "value": "clam"}],
"cwd": "${workspaceRoot}",
"console": "integratedTerminal"
 }
```

How do I build and run my application in release mode?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you found solution?

Comment: @AkmalSalikhov No, I've just given up on using VS code. I now use Qt Creator.

Comment: I ran into this problem today with a cmake project. At the bottom toolbar if you switch to Release, then the "Debug" button will launch the exe of the release version, rather than the debug .exe which does not exist in this case at all.

Comment: Maybe give your tasks.json as well.

Answer (score 0):

I recently had to figure this out also. I saw Charles Nehez's comment above, but when I went to change my configuration to "Release" I didn't have one. That led me to my c_cpp_properties.json file. In my configurations I only had one, "Debug". I cloned this configuration and created a "Release" version. The only difference between them being in the "defines:" section, one with "_DEBUG" and one without.

Then in my tasks.json, I took a closer look at the build tasks, I'm using the Microsoft C++ compiler cl.exe, so adjust your tasks accordingly. Again I had a "Debug" build task, with the "args:" section having the appropriate switches for a Debug build. Again I cloned and created a "Release" build task, adjusting the args section to remove the debug specific args.

With all this in place, I was able to select the "Release" configuration in the bottom toolbar, and was able to run the "Release" build task to produce a Release version of my executable.

Selecting the appropriate Launch configuration VS Code ran the release build version of the executable.